# How do I represent this sequence: $ 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3, \dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

I ran into a problem where I need to represent this sequence:

$$0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,\ldots$$

and this one too:

$$6,5,5,4,4,3,3,2,2 \ldots$$

But I am not sure how to represent them in a compact way.

Comment: So I guess the first one can be described as "Every integer (starting from zero) repeated twice", right?

Comment: With "represent", do you mean mathematically? Such as $a_n=\ldots$

Comment: Have a look at the 'floor' and 'ceiling' functions, and consider $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ for values of $n$

Comment: @Dr. Mathva yes, of course, mathematically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a_n$ and $6-a_n$ terms as I said in the comment: "Have a look at the 'floor' and 'ceiling' functions, and consider $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ for values of $n$"

For a different strategy, if 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1+2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \cdots$$
 in terms of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) you want to copy this, so you can get 
$$\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2} = x + 2x^3 + 3x^5 + \cdots$$
and the shifted version
$$\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2} = x^2 + 2x^4 + 3x^6 + \cdots$$
so 'gluing them together' and again shifting the whole sequence up
$$
G_1(x) = \frac{x^2+x^3}{(1-x^2)^2} =0x^0 + 0x^1 + 1x^2 + 1x^3 + 2x^4 + 2x^5 + 3x^6 + 3x^7 + \cdots
$$
which is the generating function for the sequence $0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4$ for example. The [inverse Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Inverse_Z-transform) of $G(\frac{1}{x})$ will give the sequence coefficient function $a_n$, (with an extra factor of $n!$ if an exponential generating function is used), so this can be used for more challenging sequences.

For the next one you want to subtract your sequence from the all 6's sequence $6,6,6,6,6,6, \cdots$

Consider 
$$
6 + 6x + 6x^2 + 6x^3 + \cdots = \frac{6}{1-x}
$$
then consider the series of 
$$
G_2(x) = \frac{6}{1-x} - \frac{x^2+x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}
$$
and to give you an example of the inverse Z-transform in action
$$
\mathcal{Z}^{-1}[G_2(1/x)](n) = \frac{1}{4} \left(-2 n+(-1)^{n+1}+25\right)
$$
whose terms from $n=1,2,3, \cdots$ start $6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, \cdots$. I calculated that using Mathematica, which has Z-transform and inverse Z-transform functions which are generally quite good.

Comment: awesome thought +1

Comment: I am going to accept you answer since you were the first one to consider the 'floor' and 'ceiling' functions in the comments and I think that one is a very simple way to describe them. Dr. Mathva was very close to be the first one, all the answers are fine but I can accept only one. I also think it is very interesting the different strategy that you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could for example define it recursively. Set $a_0 = a_1 = 0$ and $a_{i+1} = a_{i-1} + 1$ for $i \geq 1$.

And of course similarly for the other one.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $a_n=\big\lfloor\frac{n}2\big\rfloor$ for $n\geqslant 0$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative:

$$a_n=\dfrac n2+\dfrac{(-1)^n-1}4;$$

$$b_n=6-\dfrac n2+\dfrac{(-1)^n-1}4.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your two sequences are instances of an [interleave sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleave_sequence). Thus, you could introduce a specific notation for the interleave sequence of two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$, say $\operatorname{Inter}(u_n,v_n)$ and define your first sequence as $\operatorname{Inter}(n,n)$ and the second one as $\operatorname{Inter}(6-n,5-n)$.